# Space Issue in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

How to identify/ address the space issue in Linux. When I put

`df -h`


I get details of space availability of mounted devices. When i check the drive allocated for me is almost full.

`Filesystem Size    Used    Avail   Use%    Mounted` 
`/dev/mapper/rootvg-home    248M    236M    0   100%    /home`

You can see usage 100% and availability is 0 . How do I find any unwanted files in /home. I do lot of grep,sed,awk. Due to sed some temp files created but those are zero bytes. Apart from this any other way to identify the space, so that I can free some space !!!! 
Thanks in advance. If i dont make sense, put a comment. i will address ASAP.

Comment: This question belongs to serverfault.com

Answer (score 2):

Finds all files over 20,000KB (roughly 20MB) in size and presents their names and size in a human readable format:

```
find / -type f -size +20000k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 ": " $5 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
du -sh *
```

for human readable file size or

```
du -s * | sort -n
```

for size-sorted file size

And recursively check big directories for unwanted files